# 16 yr old male push ups + vertical?

Tags: push-ups

My friend recently asked me a question about how many push ups or chin ups he should be able to do for the "average" of a 16 year old male, roughly 5' 8 and 140 lbs. He is pretty fit in my opinion, but I still want to go to the internet to see.

He also wants to know an average vertical for the same parameters... I would say he has a 2 feet vertical as of now.

Answer (score 3):

For both push-ups and chin-ups, there are sites such as [strengthlevel](https://strengthlevel.com/strength-standards/push-ups) that allow users to enter in their own lifts to compare themselves to others. Some things you need to keep in mind when looking at this data:

1. This data is not verified, and neither is the form. The users could be posting completely garbage information, but from my experience, it seems decently accurate.
2. This data does not separate steroids users from natural athletes. This doesn't matter as much with body weight exercises, since body weight exercises are usually not the movements that people on steroids focus.
3. Only people who train will even know of these sites which is why they specify "Stronger than x% of **lifters**.

[image]

As for the vertical jump, I ran across many sites that have tables for averages for different ages. Many of them link back to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_jump). It looks as though that source has since been removed. After going through the web archives for that page, the original source was a book titled Training for Soccer Players written by Marc Briggs, so I don't think the data looking like this can be applied to the general population.

[image]

Another [article](https://www.jumpinguniverse.com/average-vertical-jump/) posts some other tables for different ages without any sources claiming it is the average vertical jump for high school athletes and then goes as low as 10 years old. It almost seems as though there hasn't been any reliable study to measure this and people are just making numbers up.

[image]